# Difference between front and rear tires

Tags: tire

I've found some manufacturers have front-only or rear-only tire models. What is the actual difference between front and rear tires? Why specific tire supposed to be used only on front/rear wheel?

**UPDATE**

Very good answer to my question can be found here: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/21613/4114

Comment: Yes, this especially this answer http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/21613/4114 Thanks!